# Trying to detect faces using OpenCv's inbuilt face detector

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, detection, face-detection

**Face Detection using OpenCV's inbuilt face detector.**

What does the code between the asterisks mean?

A caffe model is being used here.

```
    # loop over the detections
for i in range(0, **detections.shape[2]**):
    # extract the confidence (i.e., probability) associated with the
    # prediction

    confidence = **detections[0, 0, i, 2]**

    # filter out weak detections by ensuring the `confidence` is
    # greater than the minimum confidence
    if confidence > args["confidence"]:
        # compute the (x, y)-coordinates of the bounding box for the
        # object

        **box = detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([w, h, w, h])
        (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box.astype("int")**

        # draw the bounding box of the face along with the associated
        # probability
        text = "{:.2f}%".format(confidence * 100)

        **y = startY - 10 if startY - 10 > 10 else startY + 10
        cv2.rectangle(image, (startX, startY), (endX, endY),
            (0, 0, 255), 2)**

        cv2.putText(image, text, (startX, y),
            cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.45, (0, 0, 255), 2)

# show the output image
cv2.imshow("Output", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```